# Centering an IMG tag without using a DIV?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to center IMG tags using CSS? Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
   <img src="one.png" width="200px" height="200px" />
   <img src="two.png" width="400px" height="400px" />
</body>
```

I'd like one.png to appear above two.png, with both images centered in the browser window. 
Can this be done using CSS and without using a DIV? Thanks!

Comment: Do you just want them horizontally centered, or vertically, too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, just use:

```
img {
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/r8Tbm/2/)**

Comment: or `text-align:center` on the parent.. http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/SWHe8/